# Dynamic table with pagination and Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a Dynamic table with only showing 10 records and using pagination to show the next 10 records. I want a search function. I follow this guide http://www.vonloesch.de/node/23 But instead I can only search on the first 10 records.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have the entire table contents client side and are choosing to only show 10? or do you actually only have 10 records and that's it

Comment: I have the entire table content sir, for example the table contains 20 records, the first page of the pagination contains only 10 records and when I click next the other 10 records is there too.

Answer (score 0):

This function will filter rows of the entire table based on each row's contents rather than just one cell as in the link you provided.

```
// text => the text to search for
// _id => id of table to filter
// noOfHeaderRows => number of header rows :)
function filterTable( text, _id, noOfHeaderRows ) {

    var table = document.getElementById( _id ), contents, row;

    for (var r = noOfHeaderRows; r < table.rows.length; r++){

        row = table.rows[r];
        contents = row.textContent || row.innerText; 
        contents = contents.toUpperCase();
        text = text.toUpperCase();

        if( contents.indexOf( text ) > -1 ) {
            row.style.display = "";
        } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
        }

    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/wVvsa/2/)

Comment: on your example sir on the Fiddle what does this mean 
filter( "hello", "t" ); ? do i need to change it or where do i need to add it?

Comment: I also need a textbox to input the text I want to search.

Comment: @user1805832 I have added an explanation of each paramater. All you have to do is adapt that to your table

Comment: How about sir  I also need a textbox to input the text I want to search

Comment: @user1805832 I have answered your first question. Google can answer your second question :)

Comment: this is what i did `<p>Search: 
  <input name="filter" onkeyup="filterTable(this, 'Supp', 1)" type="text">
</p>` is that right sir?

Comment: @user1805832 if you feel the question you posted has been answered you should check it as the answer :)

Comment: would it be possible if you could tell the second asnswer sir?